# Permissions schema with relation to all Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*Rewriting the question again:*

My goal is make a permissions scheme using cancan gem. This permission scheme will be editable to automaticaly build the cans and can'ts in the Ability file. The permissions will be related to all the models on the application so I need a Role model, a Model model and a relation between with a `has_many :though` relation between them. This is all fine but I don't want to have to add records for each Model in the application, I want the models to be available by listing the `Activerecord::Base` descendants. So, I'm building it with the Role model, the ModelRole relation and the `Role has_many` relation and `ModelRole belongs_to` relation.

So far so good, but then, as there is no Model model (I know I would need to use other class name, model is a reserved key in ruby) I can't instance an object to relate to Role and save the role permission scheme in ModelsRoles, so I have to do it manually, but that feels akward.

Is this the better way? is there another way? or I should write the MyModel class to avoid all this and "eat my veggies"?

Comment: This is rather hard to understand, but it sounds like you might want a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: The thing is, I want a HABTM relation with Mods and Models, but I want to skip the Models model so I can use the list of all `Activerecord::Base` subclases. This is to avoid maintaining the Models model and avoid using de `Model`  reserved keyword from Rails

Comment: Yes, I simplified in the second response.

Comment: IMHO it may help to edit your question to something more concrete, to make it easier to understand quickly, such as Ruby's typical examples of Song, Album, Artist. Your current question sounds to me like you want a dynamically-contructed HABTM.

Comment: I think your logic for the association is backwards. Look at how you would use it. Would you Article_title a Tag? No, you Tag an Article_title. It would seem that Article_Titles can have many Tags and Tags can belong to many Article_Titles. Your edit to the question is still kind of vague. You could map out your data structure, that might make it clearer. You say you want to be able to tag a dynamically created list, but then how will you know what tag goes with what article? How will it persist if no in the DB?

Comment: Ok, I see there is no interest in the subject, if someone crosses this path and want to know what I did, I did the "pretend" you have the models and do a has_many on the model with the relation table and the Activerecord operations have to go by hand (create, update, delete) the read part is handled well by the relation structure. To avoid doing any of this, just do a your_model Model.